# Getting interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV

Tags: tensorflow

All I know is that the error occurs when this branch gets executed and the `weights` from it get passed down to `tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets`:

```
# ...
elif pretrain_cfg.schedule == PretrainSchedule.CONVERGE_LINEARLY:
    logger.info('[%s] - Pretrain: Using CONVERGE_LINEARLY schedule' % self.name)
    a = tf.minimum(tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float64, shape=(1,)), global_step / max_pretrain_steps)
    b = tf.maximum(tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float64, shape=(1,)), 1 - global_step / max_pretrain_steps)
    weights = a * const_task_weights + b * pretrain_task_weights

return tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets(datasets, weights=weights)
```

The following works:

```
weights = tf.cond(
    tf.greater(global_step, max_pretrain_steps),
    true_fn=lambda: const_task_weights,
    false_fn=lambda: pretrain_task_weights
)
```

but for some reason this here causes the `SIGSEGV`:

```
a = tf.minimum(tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float64, shape=(1,)), global_step / max_pretrain_steps)
b = tf.maximum(tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float64, shape=(1,)), 1 - global_step / max_pretrain_steps)
weights = a * const_task_weights + b * pretrain_task_weights
```

I don't really see what the problem is but the problem comes definitely from this line:

```
weights = a * const_task_weights + b * pretrain_task_weights
```

The question is why. It might not be valid to have a dependency to the `global_step` in this context as since the `weights` parameter of `sample_from_datasets`.

However, in `sample_from_datasets` I don't see anything suspicious since inside `sample_from_datasets` the first thing that happens is

```
weights = ops.convert_to_tensor(weights, name="weights")
```

So passing a tensor to it should be fine.

Any ideas?

---

Error output:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into /data/translation/multi-problem/hi2en/model/512-3-1-1024/de2en.hi2en/c19cfad259cad911/model.ckpt.
bash: line 1:  4153 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) env "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"="0" "LIBRARY_ROOTS"="/Users/username/Library/Caches/PyCharm2018.2/remote_sou...

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Comment: A segfault when trying to save a checkpoint is IMO a reason to open a bug report issue. Even assuming you're doing something wrong, there should be checks in place to prevent this kind of situation. Can't say much more, I really have no clue of what the source of the error might be, as I don't know exactly what happens when TF saves a checkpoint and how this plays with the way you handle weights.

Comment: @GPhilo Sounds reasonable. I am going to open an issue on github :)

Comment: @GPhilo It was actually my own fault (see answer). :D

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it turns out the problem is **not** with tensorflow directly - actually not at all.

The problem was because `const_task_weights` and `pretrain_task_weights` did not have the same shape. I did not validate the input and had a bug somewhere else.

Just be aware that you might get this kind of error if the shapes do not match.

I guess this cannot be checked or determined by tensorflow so that will be something the user has to take care of (citation needed).